# Backup plan for dictionary (in matrix diagnalization)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm writing a code using Python to find the shared eigenvalues and eigenvectors two matrices A and B, both of which in my case are off-diagonal with entries 1. Thus, the shared eigenvalues are 1,1,-1,-1. I hope the program could return each of the eigenvalues with all of the eigenvectors, which means both 1 and -1 have 2 'values' (eigenvectors). However, using the dictionary, I cannot give two values to a single key. Here's my code, how can I fix that? Can I still use 'dictionary' to achieve this? Thanks!

```
def simultaneous_eig1(A, B):
    epsilon = 10**-10
    vals, vecs = la.eig(A)
    degen = {}
    print(vals)
    print(vecs)
    for n in range(0, len(vals)):
        for m in range(0, len(vals)):
            # equality up to certain precision
            if np.abs(vals[m] - vals[n]) < epsilon and m != n:
                degen.get(vals[m], vecs[:,n])
        degen[vals[n]] = np.array([vecs[:,n]])
    return degen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a list as the value of your dictionary item:

```
degen[vals[n]] = []  # do this once for each key
```

... and then append the actual value(s) to that list:

```
degen[vals[n]].append(np.array([vecs[:,n]]))
```

The complication is that you need to create the empty list if the key is encountered for the first time; if it is already there, you need to skip the list initialization.

You can solve this using [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
degen.setdefault(vals[n], []).append(np.array([vecs[:,n]]))
```

For clarity, it is convention to assign complicated values to simpler expressions, such as:

```
value = np.array([vecs[:,n]])
degen.setdefault(vals[n], []).append(value)
```

The last line needs to be called for each of your eigenvalues.

---

If values don't repeat and order does not matter, you can also use a `set()` instead of `[]`. You will then have to replace `append` with `add` (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.add)).